# Why cookies are just signed instead of encrypted?

Tags: networking, cookies

Generally, a cookie is signed to prevent tampering.

But why not just encrypt it?

If it is because of performance, parsing a signed cookie still needs to decrypt the signature. Is there really a huge difference?